# Kivy doesn't works with Python3 but works with Python2

Tags: lubuntu, python3, python-2.7, kivy

I installed the Kivy library for Python3 but when I import the Kivy library, the interpreter gives an error 'No module name Kivy' even though I installed the package python3-kivy. I'm able to import the Kivy library in Python2 and not in Python3. I'm using Lubuntu 18.04. Any solutions?

Comment: How did you install kivy? Could you give us the command?

Comment: I installed Kivy using the command: sudo apt install python3-kivy.